# How to delete an apprequest

Tags: facebook-graph-api, apprequests

According to the documentation I must remove an apprequest when a user has accepted it. There is however a problem with this.

When I accept an apprequest, I will be redirected to my app. But in the url parameters only the apprequestid(s) are included. The userId of the current user is unavailable.
My app doesn't require authentication so I can't access the current users data.

How do I remove the apprequest for this user when I don't have acces to the userdata or accesstoken as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting):

The old method of the apprequest allowed me to extract the userid from the requestid. This is not possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have authentication to "tamper" with user data - that includes app invitations.
However with an `App Access Token` you might be able to delete the post without authenticating your user (you'll still have to aquire their UID - possibly from the `signed_request` .  You can read at [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) about app login and how to retrieve the correct access token.

Comment: But in order to delete an apprequest with the app accesstoken i still need the userId of the current user.
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<request_id>_<user_id>]?
      access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]. And i still don't have access to that with the app access token.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot about the change to the `request_id` formation.  Looks like you'll have to require at least the minimal permissions from the user in order to handle his/her apprequests.

Comment: maybe you can use the signed_request that is passed to your application to find out who the user is...

Comment: The signed_request doesn't contain detailed userinfo if the user hasn't granted your app access.. Guess its not posible. A flaw in the design i guess.. Thanks for answering so fast ;)

Comment: so then you'll have to request authentication.